# Error 500 from registering new User using Flask

Tags: flask

Im trying to use .register to add a new user

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def register():
    """
    Handle creation of accounts
    """
    registerForm = Register()
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if not registerForm.validate_on_submit():
                abort(400)
            email = registerForm.email.data
            password_hash = generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data)
            new_user = User(
                email=email, password_hash=password_hash, created=dt.utcnow()
            )
            add_user(new_user)
            flash(f"Account Registered. Please Log In.", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        except BadRequest:
            flash("Failed to register account.", "danger")

    return render_template(
        "register.html", form=registerForm, title="Rentier | Sign Up"
    )
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
def register():
    """
    Handle creation of accounts
    """
    registerForm = Register()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            print("Before validate_on_submit")
            if not registerForm.validate_on_submit():
                print("Validation failed")
                abort(400)

            email = registerForm.email.data
            password_hash = generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data)
            new_user = User(
                email=email, password_hash=password_hash, created=dt.utcnow()
            )
            add_user(new_user)  # Assuming add_user is defined somewhere in your code

            flash(f"Account Registered. Please Log In.", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        except BadRequest as e:
            print(f"Bad request during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Invalid request. Please check your input.", "danger")
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(f"Integrity error during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Email address already in use. Please choose a different one.", "danger")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Failed to register account. Please try again later.", "danger")

    print("Rendering template")
    return render_template(
        "register.html", form=registerForm, title="Rentier | Sign Up"
    )
```

```
class Register(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField("Email address", validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField(
        "Password", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8), password_validator, EqualTo("confirm", "Passwords must match")]
    )

    confirm = PasswordField("Confirm password")

    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    # Primary Key
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Email
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # Password Hash
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    # Created
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    history = db.relationship("Entry", backref="user", lazy=True)
```

```
# Debug Configuration File

ENV="development"
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY="TestingTesting123"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///database.db"
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

I have managed to create the user database but whenever i try to add a new user with email and password, i get

```
500 Internal Server Error
Looks like something went wrong!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

and i already tried debugging but cannot seem whats wrong it, even login also produces the same error my app.py looks like

```
from application import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug= True)
    # app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    # app.run()
```

but if i can run thewebsite i cannot understasnd why a simple creating a new user will result in error.
My terminal looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C33pn.png)
Im new to flask so if my code have errors please guide me.

my html is

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}


<form class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 mx-auto" name="signupForm" method="POST" action="/register" novalidate>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.email.label(class_='form-label') }}
        {{ form.email(class_='form-control')}}
        <span class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</span>
        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
        <br>
        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.password.label(class_='form-label') }}
        {{ form.password(class_='form-control')}}
        <span class="form-text">Passwords should be at least 8 characters long, containing at least one uppercase, lowercase, number and special character.</span>
        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.confirm.label(class_='form-label') }}
        {{ form.confirm(class_='form-control')}}
        {% for error in form.confirm.errors %}
        <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.submit(class_='btn btn-success') }}
    </div>
</form>
<p class="text-center">
    Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

It says i managed to have post in purple so whats really wrong here?